# Carousel images not showing in Firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

have strange situation i just moved my webpage to new hosting. I check everything and it was ok on my local pc. Webpage is working on firefox,chrome,ie without problem. Unfortunetly when moved to hotsting provider and check it for all 3 webbrowser only for firefox the carousel images are not shown - the carousel itself is showing up, i can even switch images which are empty. What can be wrong? On my local pc using firefox its showing up.

Comment: Can you show us some code like the paths to the images so that we can look if you made an mistake. Also: take a look in the webconsole of firefox. Enable `net` in the firefox webconsole to see if the images are loading. What you also can do is go to google and shearch if more people are having the same 
problem with this host.

Answer (score 1):

check if image name contains space or image extension is in upper case.
If you have image with ".JPG" extension and you call it by ".jpg" ( Notice change in Case) locally it may work but wont on server.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that every image i got was as below (look slash):

```
<img alt="" src="carousel\7.png">
```

and that was working for IE,chrome but not for fireofx (only local pc firefox)

when i chagned to that form every image:

```
<img alt="" src="carousel/7.png">
```

since that its working also firefox on hosting side.